# Flask app with Google login: Missing access token from userinfo_endpoint

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, openid

I'm trying to implement Google login on a Flask web app with OAuth2.0/OpenID using the tutorial found [here](https://realpython.com/flask-google-login/).

Everything is working until the callback function, which looks like this:

```
GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL = (
    "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
)

def get_google_provider_cfg():
    return requests.get(GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL).json()

@app.route("/login/callback")
def callback():
    code = request.args.get("code")
    google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
    token_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["token_endpoint"]

    token_url, headers, body = client.prepare_token_request(
    token_endpoint,
    authorization_response=request.url,
    redirect_url=request.base_url,
    code=code
    )
    token_response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body,
        auth=(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
    )

    userinfo_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["userinfo_endpoint"]
    uri, headers, body = client.add_token(userinfo_endpoint) # ERROR HERE
    userinfo_response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=body)
    # Code continues....
```

When it gets to the client.add_token(userinfo_endpoint) function at the bottom, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Missing access token

I've Googled as much as I can but I'm little lost where to start debugging this one as it appears to be on the OpenID side.